# Where is GeoNetwork error log?

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, log

I'm getting an error while importing metadata to geonetwork (picture below):

[image]

`TransformerConfigurationException Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.`

I would like to see the details about the error, but I can't find the error log. GeoNetwork is installed on localhost (Tomcat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is in `catalina.out` and `geonetwork.log` in Tomcat's logs folder. In a Linux system with Tomcat installed from the distribution packages they usually are in `/var/log/tomcat${TOMCAT_VERSION}` folder.

Comment: Thanks! Found the error I was looking for in Tomcat9.0/logs folder in tomcat9-stderr.2019-07-03.log